# How to find a sibling HTML table element by specific href using Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using Beautiful Soup, I am trying to scrape data from HTML tables which look like the following:

```
<table class="ipl-zebra-list ipl-zebra-list--fixed-first release-dates-table-test-only">
  <tr class="ipl-zebra-list__item release-date-item">
   <td class="release-date-item__country-name"><a href="/calendar/?region=de">Germany
   </a></td>
   <td align="right" class="release-date-item__date">15 September 2017</td> <td align="left" class="release-date-item__attributes">(Oldenburg Film Festival)
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ipl-zebra-list__item release-date-item">
    <td class="release-date-item__country-name"><a href="/calendar/?region=gb">UK
    </a></td>
    <td align="right" class="release-date-item__date">23 March 2018</td> <td class="release-date-item__attributes--empty"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I am looking for the date which appears in the sibling element to the `<td>` element which includes the following href:

```
<a href="/calendar/?region=gb">UK
```

In the example above this the 23 March 2018 but the date is different for every instance in which the href occurs. However the href is always identical.

To summarise, I am looking for the data which appears in the adjacent cell to href listed above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to have the country name and the date linked to that country name you could create a dictionary like this:

```
html = '''<table class="ipl-zebra-list ipl-zebra-list--fixed-first release-dates-table-test-only">
  <tr class="ipl-zebra-list__item release-date-item">
   <td class="release-date-item__country-name"><a href="/calendar/?region=de">Germany
   </a></td>
   <td align="right" class="release-date-item__date">15 September 2017</td> <td align="left" class="release-date-item__attributes">(Oldenburg Film Festival)
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ipl-zebra-list__item release-date-item">
    <td class="release-date-item__country-name"><a href="/calendar/?region=gb">UK
    </a></td>
    <td align="right" class="release-date-item__date">23 March 2018</td> <td class="release-date-item__attributes--empty"></td>
 </tr>
</table>'''


html_code = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

countries = html_code.find_all('td', class_='release-date-item__country-name')
dates = html_code.find_all('td', class_='release-date-item__date')

dates_as_dic = {}
for i in range(len(dates)):
    dates_as_dic[countries[i].text.strip()] = dates[i].text

print(dates_as_dic)
```

output:

```
{'Germany': '15 September 2017', 'UK': '23 March 2018'}
```